# interactive python console for gtk application

Tags: python, console, gtk

Looking for suggestion on the best way to embed a python interpreter inside a python application, in the same way that gedit geany and rhythmbox work, so you can modify your program on the fly. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This recipe](https://gist.github.com/rpmuller/5987615) is something I wrote maybe 6 years ago, and hasn't been updated (or used) since then, so I can't really recommend it as "answering" your question, but it might provide some clues to how you can solve the problem. Hope it helps, and good luck!

Comment: thanks for the example i have a working example program i will post below, tested with gtk 3 using a textview :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution i came up for future use :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# [SNIPPET_NAME: gtk3 interactive textview]
# [SNIPPET_CATEGORIES: gtk]
# [SNIPPET_TAGS:interactive, gtk3]
# [SNIPPET_DESCRIPTION: using gtk3 textview run python code on running program]
# [SNIPPET_AUTHOR: Oliver Marks ]
# [SNIPPET_LICENSE: GPL]

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
import code
import math


class interactiveGtk:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Gtk.Window()
        window.set_default_size(380, 300)
        window.connect("destroy", lambda w: Gtk.main_quit())

        box = Gtk.VBox()

        self.drawingarea = Gtk.DrawingArea()

        textarea = Gtk.TextView()
        textarea.connect('key-press-event', self.key_pressed)
        self.textbuffer = textarea.get_buffer()
        self.textbuffer.set_text('self.show_drawing(True)')

        self.drawingarea.connect("draw", self.area_expose_cb)

        box.add(self.drawingarea)
        box.add(textarea)

        window.add(box)
        window.show_all()

        self.drawarea = False

        """interactive mode interpreter, pass locals() so we can access our programs functions and variables"""
        self.interpreter = code.InteractiveInterpreter(locals())

    def show_drawing(self, state):
        """self.show_drawing(True) to enable showing the lines"""
        self.drawarea = state

    def test(self):
        """run self.test() when program is running to print this message"""
        print 'hello world'

    def area_expose_cb(self, widget, context):
        """expose event lets draw, lines will only display if we run self.show_lines first.
        demonstrating running state change of our program"""
        self.style = self.drawingarea.get_style()
        #self.gc = self.style.fg_gc[Gtk.STATE_NORMAL]
        if self.drawarea is True:
            self.drawing(context, 210, 10)

    def drawing(self, cr, x, y):
        """ draw a circle in the drawing area """
        cr.set_line_width(10)
        cr.set_source_rgb(0.5, 0.8, 0.0)

        cr.translate(20 / 2, 20 / 2)
        cr.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, 2 * math.pi)
        cr.stroke_preserve()

        cr.set_source_rgb(0.3, 0.4, 0.4)
        cr.fill()

    def key_pressed(self, widget, event):
        """keypresses only intrested in return, run code in textview on return"""
        if event.keyval == Gdk.keyval_from_name('Return'):
            start = self.textbuffer.get_iter_at_line(0)
            lineend = start.get_chars_in_line()
            end = self.textbuffer.get_end_iter()
            source = self.textbuffer.get_text(start, end, False)

            """run our code in the textview widget, put output in the terminal we may want to put this into the gui somewhere"""
            print self.interpreter.runsource(source, "<<console>>")


interactiveGtk()
Gtk.main()
```